# Checkbox (or SOMETHING) to activate a row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My wife runs a dance school, and occasionally needs to calculate the average age on a given date of a group of dancers. I'm not having a problem with the age calculation and averaging, but I wish to add a feature:

My sheet has all dancers in her company listed. Currently, we copy them all, paste to another sheet, and then delete the ones not included. That's a PITA, so instead I'd like to be able to put a checkbox in the first column, that when checked, would INCLUDE the associated age column in the calculation. So, she could just go down the list, click the included dancers, and it would calculate the average JUST for the selected ones and ignore everybody else.

Honestly, at this point, I have ZERO idea of where to start to do this and need a gentle push in the correct direction. Assume I'm an idiot and know almost nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example sheet with the new checkbox feature to illustrate the function:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G8LJyS10yi1HIa2MNHCbWUJPso9QAit3i0cO8A-Uw3A/edit?usp=sharing

I placed the formula above the "Age" column (Column C), and the Checkboxes in Column A:

```
=iferror(AVERAGEIF(A3:A,TRUE,C3:C),"NO DANCER'S SELECTED!")
```

This also displays an error message in case no dancer's are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It looks for 'y' in column A. Assumes names are in column B and ages in column C. You can adjust the columns to match you sheet, and change the 'y' to whatever value you want to enter. It will average the ages of the rows with 'y' in column A:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A,"=y",C2:C)
```